# Rotativa not working when impersonate enabled on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, rotativa

I am using Rotativa to generate a PDF from a view. It works on my localhost, but when I push to my server it does not work at all. The Server has Windows Authentication and Impersonate enabled which I need to have for this site.

This is the error I get when I try to run the code on the server

> Qt: Could not initialize OLE (error 80070005) Error: Failed loading
>   page
>   https://api.mydomain.com/Reports/RedBluePDF?community=CommunityName&procedure=GetTasks
>   (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with
>   --load-error-handling ignore) Exit with code 1 due to http error: 1003

Here is my code:

```
public byte[] getReportsPDF(string community, string procedure)
        {

            byte[] pdfBytes = new byte[] { };

            RouteData route = new RouteData();
            route.Values.Add("controller", "SiteSuperReports");
            route.Values.Add("action", "RedBluePDF");

            this.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), route, this);

            if (procedure == "GetProductionTasks")
            {

                var actionPDF = new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("RedBluePDF", new { community = community, procedure = procedure })
                {
                    PageSize = Size.A4,
                    PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
                    PageMargins = { Left = 1, Right = 1 }
                };

                try
                {
                    pdfBytes = actionPDF.BuildFile(ControllerContext);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Write(e.Message.ToString());
                }
            }

            return pdfBytes;
        }
```

And here is RedBluePDF Method, this just returns a View:

```
public ActionResult RedBluePDF(string community, string procedure) {
     return View();
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how come this is not working on my server, but is on my localhost? And How do I get it work on my server.

Comment: 80070005 is access denied. This rotativa things seems to be spawning an exe (wkhtmltoimage.exe or wkhtmltopdf.exe) when called. Try to give the execute right on this .exe to the server user who runs your code (or everyone to test if it changes anything)

Comment: Do you have `Javascript` on your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of this solutions:

1- Go to IIS > Site > Authentication, click on "ASP.NET Impersonation" and DISABLE it.

2- If you're calling a script or a file or whatever, specify the used protocol:

```
src="//api.mydomain.com/?????
```

to:

```
src="http://api.mydomain.com/?????
```

3- In your Application Pool's configuration, under Process Model, there's an option "Load User Profile". It comes as False by default, set it as true.

Comment: I need Impersonate enabled on my site.

Comment: I will try option 3

Comment: @user979331 hope it will solve the problem, or try to upgrade your Rotativa version.

Comment: Im at version 1.7.3

Comment: Option 3 did not work :( I get the same error (and yes I restarted the application pool)

Comment: @user979331 give this a try:
public ActionResult RedBluePDF(string community, string procedure) {
var model = new GeneratePDFModel();     
return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("GeneratePDF", model){FileName = "TestViewAsPdf.pdf"}
}

Comment: I tried this: `public ActionResult RedBluePDF(string community, string procedure) { var model = new GeneratePDFModel(); return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("GeneratePDF", model){FileName = "TestViewAsPdf.pdf"}` What it did was return a PDF File as an attachment, now how would I call this method and get the bytes of the attached file?

Comment: @user979331 use this instead: public ActionResult RedBluePDF(string community, string procedure) {
var pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = "pdfbytes" }) 
                                                     { FileName = "Test.pdf" };

            var binary = pdfResult.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);

            return File(binary, "application/pdf");}

Comment: I have no idea hows this would help, I am just running into the same problem again.

Comment: @user979331 I saw that it is likely that the error starts from this step

Comment: Its failing on this line `pdfBytes = actionPDF.BuildFile(ControllerContext);` if I goto https://api.mydomain.com/Reports/RedBluePDF?community=CommunityName&procedure=GetTasks  in my browser everything is loaded up properly there.